# Saving a C# class definition

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, reflection.emit

Is there any way to save an entire class definition for a C# object to a file / data store?

I use the ***[Serializable]*** tag and ***ISerializable*** interface to do this already, but both of these rely on the object definition being in the assembly at run time.

What I'm looking for is a solution to the following scenario:

1) User creates object ***MyClass*** in my software and saves it

For the purpose of this example, ***MyClass*** is a stand-alone object that doesn't rely on any other class in the system:

i.e. this could be the entire definition:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public void DoSomething() { /* do something, like Console.Write(""); */ }
}
```

2) We release a patch that removes ***MyClass*** from the system

3) User loads the saved ***MyClass*** from step 1 and calls ***DoSomething()*** on it - and has the function work exactly the same as it did before the patch removed the class from the system

---

Is there any way this can be done without reflection / emit trickery?

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at defining interfaces?

Comment: Will, I agree. Often times, when smaller software companies "upgrade" their product, they do so with the caveat that "your old stuff will likely no longer work." I'm trying to have my cake and eat it too - by telling them "your old stuff will most definitely still work, we just don't support it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this won't work without emitting the type definition.  What you are trying to do is actually save off the code (otherwise, how would `DoSomething` work?) - which is what the compiler does for you.  Plain serialization will never work for you here.

So, if you need to save behavior as well as state, you need to either keep the historical code around, use some type of reflection emit trickery to persist the type definition as a loadable assembly, or use dynamic programming tricks that treat data as executable code.

When I have had do versioned serialization before, I normally have custom serialization logic and a "version" attribute on the object - using this I can create a type that I've moved and renamed - say `SomeClass` to `Archive.SomeClassV3`.   You can use [Version Tolerant Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28VS.80%29.aspx) for this, but I prefer to implement [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) and use serialization proxies if this is required.   (Well, actually I prefer to avoid this problem altogether!)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could keep all of these serializable classes in their own DLLs, package the DLLs with the application, and have the DLLs loaded at runtime. That way, even if you remove the classes from the latest version of the application, the loaded DLLs will still work.

This seems like a scary approach, though ... now you have clients running ancient code that you no longer even have in your source control repository. How are you supposed to debug that?

Comment: I agree, it's definitely a scary idea. I'm just trying to "think outside of the box," if you will.

Comment: <pedantic> It's prob still in your sourcecode repostory, source control is forever.</pedantic>

Answer (score 0):

You talking about not class-property serialization, but about process-serialization (or method-, doesn't matter). But unlike property serialization, this should contain MSIL-code that runs when you need it. So you must somehow translate it to a bin-code and then run by Assembly.Load, for example. I guess this is not an easy way to do this. So, if this is possible - store your implementation of MyClass to a separate dll, or as a string (in c# language) for further compilation and execution by reflection.